# Upload a File in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a button `Upload File` . As soon as user clicks on it he should be able to select the file through OS menu and display contents on *textarea* of html tag.

I have tried **node.js** 'fs' module. But I want users to select the type and file name in UI.

How will I be able to implement this feature in **React Js** or simple J**avascript**(*React js uses .js file as well*)?

I am trying to get **.json** file in particular so the type is **.json**.

Comment: Read this article to get into it: [react js file upload](https://medium.com/ecmastack/uploading-files-with-react-js-and-node-js-e7e6b707f4ef). Its well explained there. Also, See this dragndrop/upload [component](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone). You can also use some easy to installiert npm [components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-uploader)

Comment: You are mixing concepts of client and server side code. Frankly you need invest much more time to learn at least some basics of web development and applications before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could go about doing this. I'm not 100% sure on what your use case is but the way I see it, if you're doing some sort of front end only system/image manipulation thing, you could load the image into js memory? or the browser store as a base64 encoded image?

Otherwise if it's a normal app where this image needs to live in a database after being uploaded, you're going to want to POST it to an endpoint somewhere to do so. You can look at a library like [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) which also has a [react component](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone)

Comment: I have to read the contents of file once the file is selected through menu.